# Is there any way of changing colors of text in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What I want to know is if you can change the default color value for something like comments:

```
//Yo
```

Which are by default, green. I want to know if you could make this red black or any other colors.

Also as a bonus, is there anything that works kind of like a little sticky note, but in the code? Some sort of image or something that would be easily recognized if you were scrolling through lots of code very fast. Like a place mark, an eye catcher. That doesn't affect the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode menu->Preferences->Fonts and Colors, then have fun...

To put markers in your code you can use

```
#pragma mark - Something
```

It will then show in the drop down menu showing all your functions/declarations.

---

Edit: for newer Xcode versions, just use:

```
// MARK: - comment
```

Comment: What do I replace "Something" with? haha I just used this and I put a bunch of random letters, I didn't see it in the debugger or anything

Comment: It's not meant to have any effect on compilation, it just puts a marker, which you can see in the bar just above your code view, with the list of declarations in your current file.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Xcode preferences, Fonts & Colors.